# Javascript download images from URL

Tags: javascript, web, download

I have a problem: I would like to download the images from this website:

http://www.oasidelleanime.com/minisiti/raccontastorie/Fascicolo1/index.htm

I could save the page but there is a problem: the images you see in the page I linked are just thumbnails. I need to download the 'real' images, the ones you open when you click on the thumbnail. My problem is: there is any script I can use so that I do not have to open all the images manually (which is a pain, to be sincere)?

My best regards,
*Alessandro*

Comment: Use Firefox and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you by script mean javascript the short and simple answer is NO. This is because of a security vulnerability called cross-site scripting. Wikipedia has an article about it, see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

But it may be possible to download the images with a shellscript using wget. The following script may work:

```
#! /bin/bash
# use this script for downloading websites using 'wget' utility
# replace URL field with the URL to be downloaded

URL="$1"

wget -Nrkpl 0 $URL

# wget flags and their functions
# -r = recursive: follows the links
# -k = changes links adresses to their local file adress
# -p = downloads images
# -l = recursion level. 0 for infinite.
```